# factorization optimization of numbers

Tags: algorithm, time, numbers, refactoring

How to optimize this code given `N<=1000`? I tried factorization of each number but it is time consuming:

```
cnt = 0 ;
 for int i=1 to N
    for int j=1 to N
        for int k=1 to N
        if(i*j)%k==0 
         cnt = cnt + 1
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier for people to help you if they knew the purpose of the algorithm. Think how you would explain the problem to a coworker who had offered to help, and edit the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of factors of a number? Of every number less than `N`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you do some overcounting:

For each pair i,j that has value x = i * j you run a loop k times, yet theres lots of pairs of i*j that give same value

And you use modulus N^3 times, remember modulus is expensive.

Optimizations:

1. Instead of overcounting all i * j pairs, store them in hashtable/array and count their frequency
2. Instead of using modulus use some maths for optimization, when some number x divided by k gives modulo of 0 ? only when x is some multiple of k, so just loop on fequencies from 0 to n*n by increments of k

Sample code (c++):

```
vector<int>freq(n*n+1); //that's just array of n*n+1 zeroes

for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
for(int j=1; j<=n; j++)
    freq[i*j]++;

int cnt = 0;
for(int k=1; k<=n; k++)
    for(int j=0; j<=n*n; j+=k) //note these loops look like n^3 at first glance yet it's something like n log (n*n) (check harmonic number if you're curious why)
    cnt+=freq[j];
```

Even more optimizations:

Well 1000 is not a lot, even if numbers take 64 bits each its like ~8KB memory. So you have an option to generate all answers in some array like answer[n] stores answer for some n, and then hardcode array of answers into the code.